# Vue.js computed property for v-bind:class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I understand how to use v-bind:class if I have a computed function returning true or false.

I would like to know if it is possible to use a computed property that matches the ID of the button being clicked and the value of that button. 
So clicking button 1 I could get the value of of that button and check if it matches the value of data model being bind to the input.

Currently the value of the button is sync'd to a Vue data property.

```
<label v-bind:class="myBtnClass">
        <input type="radio" name="button1" id="button1" value="1" v-model="valueOfBtn"> One 
</label>
<label v-bind:class="myBtnClass">
        <input type="radio" name="button2" id="button2" value="2" v-model="valueOfBtn"> Two 
</label>
```

---

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        'valueOfBtn': 1
```

---

This bit would only work for one button and clearly I don't want to repeat this block of code x times.

```
computed: {

myBtnClass: function () {
            var result = [];
            if (this.valueOfBtn) == document.getElementById('button1').value.valueOf()))
            {
                result.push('primary');
            }
            return result;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 46, accepted):

use `methods` instead:

```
export default = {
  methods: {

    myBtnClass: function(name) {
      var result = [];
      if (this.valueOfBtn) === name) {
        result.push('primary');
      }
      return result;
    },
  // ...
  }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<label v-bind:class="myBtnClass('button1')">
....
<label v-bind:class="myBtnClass('button2')">
```